# Entity Framework POCOs without behaviour - redesign needed to remove code smell

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework Model-First with `Repository` and `Unit of Work` patterns, the repositories return EF POCOs.

I assumed that I couldn’t add behaviour to my POCOs that are generated by Entity Framework, so my code is now full of things like `XyzService` which is a separate class implementing the business logic for the Entity Framework generated `Xyz POCO`.

I have the following questions:

1. This has a bad code smell as not only do I have the EF POCOs, I have a service for each POCO. In addition to  lots of classes, business logic is split outside of the business entity. Is this an example of the anaemic anti-pattern?
2. If I stick with EF, is there any way I can add behaviour (i.e. through partial classes) or other means?
3. Seeing the persistent ignorant patterns which use return business entities from data layer (in our case a repository), if I wanted to go from `EF-MODEL -> REPOSITORY-DAL -> BIZ-ENTITY` I see there would be a lot of two way mapping between the business entity and the EF model POCO. Can utilities such as Automapper gracefully handle complex relationships of nested objects that I am likely to face?
4. To reduce duplicated business entities with their counterpart EF model entities, would I not be better of removing EF and just writing my own repository implementations using LINQ to SQL for each repository?
5. Any recommended way that allows me to concentrate on the code (rather than target fixating on the EF model first as I have been), then still use Entity Framework at the end when I am ready to write the persistence layer, but avoiding a lot of extra work and mapping in doing so? Would EF Code-First be better in this regard?

If I have missed anything else of other technologies that can aid development (NHibernate for example) then please feel free to mention.

Comment: You should be able to add behaviour directly in POCOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yeah, according to [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), this is an anti-pattern. I personally don't find this anti-pattern too offensive, but some people do. Use best judgement here. If it feels wrong and is a pain to deal with, then change it.
2. [Yes](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/). Partial Classes can help with this. You can put behaviors in the partials you write.
3. [Yes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings), Automapper will automatically deal with nested objects if they have a mapping setup
4. Again, thats up to you. If EF is driving you nuts, don't use it. Use what works and what makes you feel good while you use it.
5. [Code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) was built for exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is, but this approach isn't without advantages. For example, enforcing separation between the POCOs and the business logic could allow that logic to be decoupled and supplied via dependency injection or some other means.
2. Keep in mind that partial classes cannot span multiple assemblies (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

   > All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

   This restriction could be undesirable, though you could instead use extension methods to implement the required behaviour.
3. I've not used Automapper, so Ryan's advice would apply here.
4. & 5. I have grouped these together as using Code-First would impact on your specific repository implementation. If you've not tried Code-First, I recommend taking a look at it.

In terms of repositories, my preference is for the repository to be completely generic in terms of both the POCO types we are dealing with, and the operations available. For example, with LINQ a repository could have a `Get` method that retrieves items (say, as an `IEnumerable<T>`) based upon a given `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

I like this approach because it allows the repository to be dependency injected, cleanly separates standard CRUD operations from more domain-specific ones, yet offers great opportunities for code reuse from consumers/derived classes.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the partial class answer. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

Design books, pattern books and prominent bloggers are okeay, however we developers tend to think we have to develop our projects as they suggest even when those books/articles doesn´t provide us with context enough to understand in which situations they apply and when they don´t.

There are not such a thing like a good design for all kind of application. I see you are focused on technical points and that is okay but first of that you should response to the most important question: do your requirements fit well with that design?

Remember, you have requirements, constraints, resources and time, among other considerations, which force you to be involved in some of trade-offs that has to guide your design.

For example:

- Do you really need Repositories? What is you get your entities directly using EF?
- Do you need DataModels and BizModels? What if you just use TransactionScripts?
- Do you need UoW? Why? Cannot EF handle this pretty well for you?

The answers to these questions are not something absolute, they depend on your requirements, time, budge, etc.

Now, let me tell you what I think about your questions:

1. **Yes**, it smells bad for some reasons: a) POCO objects should be, well... POCO, this is beacuse you have biz-object that, of course, have logic but... what kind of logic do the POCO objects have?
2. **Yes**, partial classes should be used for this instead of your xyzService. That is clearer and because your xysServices are no services at all!
3. **Yes**, Automapper can deal with the mapping problem. However, the it doesn´t fix the problem you probably have a lot of mappings. Again, if you don´t need it, avoid them.
4. Do you (or your company) have money and time enough to do that? Nowadays nobody avoid an ORM without a absolutely strong  reason. So, no, don´t do it!
5. Idem 4.

This is my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go down the **"Code First"** path. I used to use the EF modeling tool, with partial classes, but still had significant issues, such as lack of control on the generated code - not to mention sporadic issues with the modeller, requiring me to recreate relationships.

With "Code First" you have much better control over your POCOs, and many added benefits such as Database-Migrations, and the ability to scaffold POCOs the way you like with T4 templates and the like.

I wouldn't go back to LinqToSQL, EF is much more feature-rich and has a brighter future, IMO. EF is now open-source, I've had a few looks at the source to help with certain issues I have faced.